# Switch crazyness

Tags: switch, vlan

I have a couple of switches here which gives me a headache.
Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't the whole thing makes no sense.

So I linking 2 vlan capable switches together on a regular access port.

My machine -> Switch1 -> Switch2 -> SRV B

For start the configuration of Switch2 is on factory default, no vlans are configured.
It should act as a dumb layer2 switch.

I configure Port 1 to be a regular Untagged access port and plug a cable between it and switch B. The server on switch B is not configured to be in vlan (it has an ip address from the same range as my computer). I still cannot ping either the management interface of the switch or SRVB.

Now eventually at the very end this configuration would look like that all switches have the same vlans configured, and i can assign any ports on switch2 to be in any vlan, but if this step doesn't even work i not going to continue because i want to understand whats going wrong exactly.

On Switch1 the port where I plug into Switch to is set to be untagged port in the Default_VLAN  id = 1.

This is very frustrating, I already spent 5 hours and not getting further with it. The worse part is that it *magically* started working once then doesnt again, I reseted back the 2nd switch to factory default so now i'm back where I started.

Any answers are welcome.

Comment: What type of switches are they? Do they have dedicated uplink ports?

Comment: I'm not sure about factory default on a managed switch behaving the same as a dumb switch. You may find that the dumb switch would forward VLAN tagged frames between any ports, but the managed switch in factory default would only forward untagged frames.

Comment: Are either of these switches in a production environment? If not, then reset them to factory defaults, connect them to each other, connect a host to each one and see if you can ping between the hosts. `1.` Make sure the hosts have the appropriate ip address information. They need to be in the same Layer 3 network/subnet. `2.` Do not configure the switches in any way. Leave them at the factory default settings.

Comment: I agree with kasperd on that being a bad assumption. If you are adding switches that don't understand VLANs / aren't configured, it would seem wise to have them attached only to ports set as untagged/pvlan ports.

Answer (score 1):

Ahh by now I probably spent more work-hours on it than what this switch cost.
It is a Zyxel GS1510-24.

I found an interesting forum post about it:

"It appears that it only supports dynamic (tagged) if another switch sends it a GVRP message telling it to create a dynamic VLAN. VLAN 1 is static with no way to change it and if you use the web interface to create a new VLAN it is created as static (no choice when creating a new VLAN).

What really confused me is that it allows you to assign a port as tagged on multiple static VLAN and the apparently ignores the tags and use the port PVID."

Right now I configured VLAN 2 statically. I have 2 machines in VLAN2 on this switch which are both vlan capable as well, they can ping each other but they cannot ping any other devices and computers in VLAN2 (or any other vlans by the way) which are connected to the other switches.

It's like the VLAN id wouldn't travers as it should between the swithes.

Comment: But the inter-switch connection isn't a trunk.  It's not VLAN-capable; why would it preserve any tagging?

Comment: ftp://ftp.zyxel.com/GS1510-24/datasheet/GS1510-24_1.pdf So looking at the datasheet. Then what it is? The one thing should be a trunk is that.